# Web application with secure access for users and groups of users

Tags: java, mysql, security, jdbc

I'm working on a project with a multi-tenant database (MySQL, Java JDBC). Each tenant can be considered a "group", and each "group" has multiple "users". My main confusion is how best to secure this, so members of a group can only access data from that group, even though they're all logging in with separate credentials.

If I was just having a group-based login, it'd be simple: one schema per group, one database user with access to each schema. This could make it so that access would be completely restricted, since without that group's password no one can access that schema.

It's with the users, what I'll be calling the "application users", that things get complicated. Each application user would be associated with a group, and when that application user logs in, they would need access to the group they are associated with. In essence, they log in as an application user, and are granted the credentials for a database user.

Right now, the idea just seems to unwieldy and insecure. If there is a way for the JDBC application layer to grant access to any database level user account, then that security becomes pointless, since it would become easy to bypass.

I'm looking for guidance about how to best secure this kind of environment.

Comment: I don't see anything peculiar about this setup.  Just have a `tenant` table where every record is a relation between a user and a tenant (a given user might be associated with multiple tenants).  Other than this, use the same security you would on a single tenant setup.

Answer (score 0):

Heres a better idea than allotting different database users for different tenants, just use a table to store all Data of Group. One Table for all application users and a third relational table to link group or tenant IDs with their respective group members' userIDs.
Whenever a Group resource or data is requested by any application user, check in the relational table if the user has authority to access the group data or not. Good Luck

Comment: This will be comparatively faster to execute as you will not have to re-connect to different databases again and again for all users

Comment: That is simpler. Maybe I am overthinking things. This may be an academic exercise, but one of my focuses is on security. Using your approach, if someone can break through the application and access the database directly, all the data is vulnerable. Indeed, the webmaster would also be able to have access to all the data in this case.